# Efficient Core Data Recursion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-data, recursion

### Context

I have a Core Data entity called "LPFile" that represents a file on disk. It has an optional relationship to itself that allows files to "import" each other, like so:

imports<<---->>importedBy

### Question

Now, suppose I have this situation with Files 1, 2, 3, and 4:

File 1 is importedBY 2 and 3. Files 2 & 3 are importedBY 4. What I want to know is: if I start at file 1, what's the most *efficient* approach for finding the "base" or "end" file of this relationship (in this case, that's file 4)? I can write a simple recursive function that looks at each entity in the importedBy relationship, and follows the chain until it finds an entity with zero entities in the importedBy relationship, but I wanted to see if Core Data has a pre-baked method to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense to me. What is it you want to do with file 4? Also, do you have a constraint in place that prevents circular references like 5 importedBy 6, 6 importedBy 7, 7 importedBy or 5, or more simply 8 importedBy 9, 9 importedBy 8?

Comment: Yes, I have constraints to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: I watch these files for changes, so when File1 changes, I need to go walk the chain to File4 and do some processing.

Comment: But you don't also need to process files 2 and 3, even though they also include file 1?

Comment: @noa: Nope. The goal is to find the root or base file that starts the chain of imported files. The recursive function approach is certainly fast enough, but I thought there might be a pre-baked way to find a "relationship root" in Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data has no pre-baked method to find a root. So your way of looping through it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Altough this questions has been answered, I solved a similiar problem on a tree made by same entities by adding an attribute called with much fantasy "breadcrumb" and filling that at runtime so that if I have entity model

```
X {
 name NSString
 breadcrumb NSString
 to-many X relationship
}
```

A,B,C,D,E like that:

```
A-->B
 -->C-->D
 -->E
```

I end up with this:

```
A {
 breadcrumb /A 
 relationship B,C,E
}


B {
 breadcrumb /A/B
 relationship nil
}     

C {
 breadcrumb /A/C
 relationship D
} 

D {
 breadcrumb /A/C/D
 relationship nil
} 

E {
 breadcrumb /A/D
 relationship nil
}
```

I can say that indexing breadcrumb, make things faster, and I can do regex search.
Important, when I have an entity I can easily find its root without cycling.
Of course I had some mechanism to avoid loop and uniqueness of breadcrumb, based on 'name' attribute.